# How to copy and paste a file with the clipboard from a compressed folder using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, clipboard

How do I copy and paste a file with the clipboard from a compressed folder using [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)?

I want to paste a file from the clipboard that has been copied from a compress folder using VB.NET. By examining the clipboard, I see there is a FileGroupDescriptorW which seems to contain some information about the file. But how do I use the information to grab the file and paste it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clipboard should contain data in the format of [CF_HDROP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa313482%28v=vs.60%29.aspx). This can be converted to a file list by calling the [DragQueryFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API.

Then it's just a list of fully-qualified filenames of whatever files were copied, and now you can operate on those files. A Visual Basic example is in *[How To Obtain Files Copied from Windows Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231721)*.